# How to redirect to home after login using React( react-router v6 )?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've trying to redirect to Home Page when i click the button "Login" on my react studies, but i have no idea how to do it, because i used all the "redirects" possibles but no one worked.

The function below the is called when i click the button "login":

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMiA.png)

Here is my react router:
[the "Principal" page is the home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYNnx.png)

My code is in portuguese.

I tryed to use the "redirect("/principal");", and other functions but don't worked.

somebody can help me?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? Please [edit] the post to include a relevant [mcve] for what you are trying to do and include any details regarding any issues or problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use redirect after login, you can use the `useNavigate` hook from react-router-dom.

you would use it as below

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
const navigate = useNavigate()

if(true){
  navigate('/principal')
}
```

Simply replace the true condition, with your original if statement conditon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hooks useNavigate from react-router

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginButton = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleClick() {
    // Your login function
    navigate("/principal");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
     Login
    </button>
  );
}
```